# C function with filenames as parameters for use in R

Tags: r, c

I need to write a C function to be usein in R by calling it with .C.
The model

C model function:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_fun(void)
{ 
    FILE *fp, *fo;
    fp = fopen("infile.txt","rb");
    fo = fopen("outfile.txt","w");
    /* transfer and transform data from infile.txt to outfile.txt */
    fclose(fp)
    fclose(fo)
}
```

In want to be able use function parameters instead of the strings
"infile.txt" and "outfile.txt"
and  I could not find a way to use paramters in my_fun
to do this.
How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to use the old C interface? This would be trivial using Rcpp.

Anyway, any object passed from R has to be of type `SEXP`. A `const char *` to a string passed from R as object `SEXP A` would be obtained by `CHAR(STRING_PTR(A)[0])`. So the following function defined via a character string in R will compile:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('

  void my_fun(SEXP A, SEXP B)
  {
    FILE *fp, *fo;
    fp = fopen(CHAR(STRING_PTR(A)[0]), "rb");
    fo = fopen(CHAR(STRING_PTR(B)[0]), "w");
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fo);
  }

')
```

And once compilation is done, you can call the function as:

```r
myfun("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
```

`file1.txt` will be opened for reading and `file2.txt` will be created in the directory if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: With this I get an error   Error: STRING_PTR() can only be applied to a 'character', not a 'raw'

Comment: How are you calling the function? If the arguments are character vectors, you should not be getting this error.

Comment: I am calling this way: .C("my_fun","infile.txt", "outfile.txt") byt meanwhile i found another solution and posted it.

Comment: What wold an Rcpp solution look like?

Comment: @ErichNeuwirth see my update. For a one-off function like this you can compile on the fly with `Rcpp::cppFunction`, though for full packages you can have a whole nested directory implementing compiled functions. Note you don't even need to specify the headers.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_fun(char **infile, char **outfile)
{ 
    FILE *fp, *fo;
    fp = fopen(*infile,"rb");
    fo = fopen(*outfile,"w");
    /* transfer and transform data from infile.txt to outfile.txt */
    fclose(fp)
    fclose(fo)
}
```